# Heroku | Discord.py | FFmpeg

Tags: discord.py, ffmpeg, heroku

я хочу что бы мой бот по команде `play` проигрывал `test.mp3`.
С командой и подключением к голосовому каналу я разобрался, но я не могу понять, как мне работать с FFmpeg на Heroku.
Я не знаю какую версию FFmpeg мне скачивать для Heroku (я знаю что на серверах Heroku стоит система Linux, но подробнее информации я не нашёл).
И есть ли другой способ проигрывать аудио в discord.py, без FFmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

При перед тем, как загружать данные и код, зайдите на странице вашего приложения во вкладку **Settings**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем промотайте до раздела **Buildpacks** и нажмите на кнопку **Add buildpack**.

Туда необходимо добавить две ссылки - FFMPEG и OPUS. Второй, вроде бы, тоже нужен для нормальной работы.

https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git

https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого, все должно заработать. Если, конечно, правильно написан код, и на Heroku установлены все необходимые модули.